# Auto-associate a wide-shot image with several closeup focus points using video on iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, camera, avfoundation

Can someone point me in the right direction for this use case on an iOS device?

1. Take a wide-shot image of any subject that you want to also get closeups of images within the original wide-shot.
2. By using video, move the phone's camera closer to the specific focus points.
3. When a desired closeup point is found, the user denotes this by pressing a button or some other gesture.
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3 until all closeup points are captured.

**Even better if step 3 can be omitted by using image recognition to auto-associate the two images without direct user input.**

I understand I'll probably have to use [AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html) but I have no idea where to go after that.